# How to do the 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4... pattern?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I don't know how to create a pattern with 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4... and so on. I'm trying to use this for a long list of Pythagorean triples to use for a changing variable.

I don't know of any function in Google Sheets, or series of nested functions for that matter, that can solve this problem. I've tried typing in every number in the sequence manually, but I don't really want to do that because it is very inefficient. I want to know whether there is a formula associated with this or anything like that.

It would very much be appreciated if someone can answer this question.

Comment: You've tagged Excel as well as Google Sheets. Does that mean you'll consider solutions which work only in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in Excel or Google Sheets:

```
=REDUCE(1,SEQUENCE(5,1,2),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,SEQUENCE(c))))
```

[image]

Comment: I thought `VSTACK` and other newer Excel functions hadn't been released in Sheets yet?

Comment: It's working for me, maybe it's not available everywhere or on all platforms?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Guess I'll have to investigate.

Comment: Works in both Excel and Sheets for me. Short investigation shows that VSTACK was introduced to Sheets not a long time ago and was rolled back for a some period of time due to bugs https://support.google.com/docs/thread/202500036?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

My two cents, for both ms365 and Google-Sheets:

```
=TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(4,4,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c>r,NA(),c))),2)
```

---

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

One of ways:

```
=TOCOL(BYROW(A1:A6, lambda(x,(SEQUENCE(1,row(x))))),1)
```

Result:

[image]

Change `TOCOL` to `TOROW` if horizontal spill is needed.

Comment: Maybe a bit more general could be `=TOCOL(BYROW(SEQUENCE(n),LAMBDA(x,SEQUENCE(1,x))),1)` where n is a placeholder for max.

Comment: Neat! Only 1 and very clear input

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes they do not. Original question title had "google sheets" in it before it was edited out. These solutions are exclusively for sheets.