# Does anyone know how to do a 2,3,3,4,4,4... pattern in Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I would like to know if a series of numbers going like 2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5 can be made in Google Sheets. To explain this in a mathematical way, a changing number ***n*** will be repeated ***n -
1*** times in the cells below it. And, yes, that means that there is no '1' in the sequence because ***1 - 1 = 0***, so it will be repeated no times. Like my earlier Google Sheets question, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75693970/how-to-do-the-1-1-2-1-2-3-1-2-3-4-pattern), I don't want to have to type in the sequence manually because it is very inefficient and time-consuming.

It would be appreciated if someone could answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
=TOCOL(MAP(SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(a,WRAPROWS(a,a-1,a))),3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Producing a Sequence

**Finally (Most Efficient)**

- [A003057](https://oeis.org/A003057)

```
=LET(Num,5,INT((SQRT(8*(SEQUENCE(Num*(Num-1)/2)-1)+1)-1)/2)+2)
```

**Efficient**

- Obviously, this is based on JvdV's answer to your previous question.

```
=LET(Num,5,TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(Num-1,Num-1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c+1>r+1,NA(),r+1))),2))
```

- Why would you use this instead of the `REDUCE` version? Because the `MAKEARRAY` version takes 2 seconds to produce the max sequence that fits in an Excel sheet, the sequence with the highest number `1448`. It takes over 40 seconds with the `REDUCE` version. The same goes for your previous question. That being said, there is a great probability that `VSTACK` is the bottleneck since we are `VSTACK`-ing on each iteration while we are `TOCOL`-ing only once.

**Slow**

- Obviously, this is based on Tom Sharpe's answer to your previous question.

```
=LET(Num,5,IF(Num=2,2,REDUCE(2,SEQUENCE(Num-2,,3),LAMBDA(r,i,VSTACK(r,SEQUENCE(i-1,,i,0))))))
```

Comment: Uh oh, seems that I have form in this respect ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578695/running-max-arrayformula-for-google-sheets

Answer (score 1):

Similar to VBasic2008's answer, though without recourse to a `LAMBDA`-based function:

```
=LET(ξ,5,ζ,SEQUENCE(ξ),TOCOL(IF(ζ>TOROW(ζ),ζ,NA()),2))
```

Comment: Brilliant! That runs in just one second for the max described in my post.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yeah, I guess as wonderful as the new `LAMBDA`-based functions are, there does appear to be a small amount of overhead association with each 'mapping' they imply. Still, not often we can do without them - just noticed a shortcut in this case!